# Return value from macro without gcc braced groups

Tags: c, gcc, macros, iso, ansi-c

If i have a macro that looks like that:

```
#define some_macro(x,y,z)({
    operation1;
    operation2;
    ...;
    x+y+z; //return value
})
```

how can i make it return value without using gcc braced groups ({})? I also can't add any other arguments to the macro.
I'm getting this compiler message:

```
warning: ISO C forbids braced-groups within expressions [-Wpedantic]
```

But i need the code to be portable, not only for gcc.

Comment: Macros aren't functions, they don't "return" values. Instead macro expansion *replaces* text in the source before the language parser sees the code.

Comment: And if you want to use GCC-specific extensions (which I highly recommend against) then you need to build with them enabled (like passing `-std=gnu11` to build with C11 standard plus GCC extensions).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, i understand, but still i do need it to be a macro, not a function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But i'm asking about how to do it without gnu extensions, this is the question actually. I mean without using braced groups that are against ISO C standard

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah, so i want to know how to get the same result without using those

Comment: Then the only answer is: Functions. It's just not possible with the simple text-replacement that macros are.

Comment: And now my curiosity sets in: ***Why*** do you want to use macros? What would using macros solve that functions doesn't? What is the original and underlying problem you want to solve using such macros? If it's plain curiosity from you, then that's okay but please say so in the question itself, otherwise please ask us about the underlying and original problem directly instead (to avoid making your question an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i'm just following the task of a "homework" in university

Comment: If the assignment was issued by a competent instructor, there is a way to complete it. If the macro must evaluate to a value and must also execute statements separate from that value and cannot do it via a function, then there is no way to do it in standard C (or C portable to compilers without GCC’s statement-expressions). Therefore, either the instructor is incompetent or there is information about the problem you have not stated or have stated incorrectly. Update the post with complete information about the assignment.

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it.  The GCC syntax extension provides functionality that is not available in standard C.  Use an inline function — or a set of inline functions if the argument types vary — and accept that macros are a limited tool that are frequently abused (and you're trying to abuse them).

Comment: Ok, then i might need to ask the instructor to clarify the task. Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: If [the comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71312344/2402272) does not suffice for your purpose, then the only way to make the code portable is to engage a function. But if there *must* be a macro then you could make it expand to a call to that function.  That's something that might even be done in real life to improve the portability of existing code that uses the macro in question extensively.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) which allows multiple expressions to be combined to a single one. This is more restrictive than GCC statement expressions (which may contain variable declarations, `for`, `while`, `switch`, etc), but the comma operator works if `operation1` and `operation2` and the rest are *expressions*.

```
#define some_macro(x,y,z) (operation1, operation2, (x)+(y)+(z))
```

If this does not work you could define a function.

Comment: Prominent among the limitations of the comma operator are that its operands need to be expressions.  That precludes variable declarations; `for`, `while`, `if`, *etc*. statements; and more.  Nevertheless, this is part and parcel of a macro that itself expands to an expression, and thus evaluates to a value.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Although there cannot be loops or variable declarations, `if` could be possibly emulated using the `?:` operator

Comment: Sure, subject to the fact that the ternary operator, being in fact an operator, is subject to the same constraint of having operands that are expressions.  Plus some additional limitations on the types of its operands.